# Camel Apache: xpath to extract some value out of received XML

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

during my Camel routes, I query a server (a HTTP GET) and as a result, I receive a 200 OK with a XML body looking similar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<userProfiles xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/AEContext/xmldata">
  <userProfile name="guest">
    <userProfileAttributes>
      <userProfileAttribute name="parameter1" value="data1" nameVisibility="ALL"/>  
      <userProfileAttribute name="parameter2" value="data2" nameVisibility="ALL"/>
      <userProfileAttribute name="parameter3" value="data3" nameVisibility="ALL"/>
    </userProfileAttributes>
  </userProfile>
</userProfiles>
```

Any idea how I would be able to get the value of "parameter2" in the XML part (in my example 'data2') and store that value in an exchange property ? I guess by using an xpath expression ? Or ...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An easy way to retrieve the value would be to use the [XPath Language](http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html). It will allow you to extract the data you want and set it somewhere (header, body , ...). Here is how to set a **parameter2** header with the value:

```
<setHeader headerName="parameter2">
  <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">
    /userProfiles/userProfile/userProfileAttributes/userProfileAttribute[2]/@value
  </xpath>
</setHeader>
```

**Using Java DSL**

An example using the Java DSL and setting the message body:

```
final Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("c", "http://www.mycompany.com/AEContext/xmldata");

// existing code
from(...)
  .setBody(
    ns.xpath(
      "/c:userProfiles/userProfile/userProfileAttributes/userProfileAttribute[2]/@value",   
      String.class)
   )
   .to(...);
```

Comment: Hi Olivier, thanks already for your reply. I have 1 additional question: suppose that I am not always sure that the userProfileAttribute parameter that I need is on position 2. Is there a way to reference via Xpath to the userProfileAttribute with the name "parameter2" to get its value ?

Comment: Could it be like this: /userProfiles/userProfile/userProfileAttributes/userProfileAttribute[@name='parameter2']/@value ?

Comment: Any valid XPath expression should be supported. I just extracted the path using FOXE (http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm)

Comment: FYI: as the XML above contains a namespace, I first needed to define that namespace in my CAMEL route. Then later on, refer to it when extracting data from the XML via XPath. So, in the above example: Namespaces ns = new Namespaces ("contextinfo", "http://www.mycompany.com/AEContext/xmldata") and later on, use something like: ns.xpath("//contextinfo:userProfileAttribute[@name='subscriberName']/@value", String.class).