# Apache Camel dynamic route based on file content

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am trying to use apache camel to route file content to activemq queue. I use camel to poll xml files from a specific folder then send its content to queue. My problem is I want to send the content to dynamic queue name based on the content value. For example :
The xml file content is

```
<name="queue1"/>
```

Then it means that this one need to send to queue named "queue1". How can I use the "queue1" dynamic value to the "to:" parameter in camel route spring dsl?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the recipientList http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html if you need dynamic endpoint uris.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is save that name to header like in this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9637840/3703819

and then use [Simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) expression in Endpoint like this:

```
<recipientList>
    <simple>activemq:queue:${headers.dest}</simple>
</recipientList>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but it send to the wrong queue (it sends the content to queue named ${header.dest})

Comment: It is because Simple expressions don't work in activemq endpoint. You must use recipientList. I edited my answer - now it should work well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a xml-document, you can use xpath to extract the info and set it in a header, which you can get by using simple

http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html

http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:start")
private ProducerTemplate start;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result1")
private MockEndpoint result1;

@Test
public void testName3() throws Exception {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start")
                .setHeader("address", xpath("/address/text()", String.class))
                .recipientList(simple("mock:${header.address}"));
        }
    });
    result1.expectedMessageCount(1);
    start.sendBody("<address>result1</address>");
    result1.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```